# Can an apache module be executed directly from the command line?

Tags: apache-httpd

I have server side includes in my html files, but I want to host them on a server that doesn't support server side includes (AWS S3 in my case).

Is there a way to render the pages such that I can save the output of the preprocessor without having to interact with the full webserver (i.e. go through a full HTTP request-response cycle)?  I know I could just use `curl` but somehow I feel there is a smarter solution that I don't know of.